# MulticastSocket determine if message received was unicast

Tags: java, sockets, multicast, unicast

My server currently is able to send and receive multicast packets. I am adding the ability to also receive and send unicast packets. So I created "DatagramSocket uniRecv" and "DatagramSocket uniSend" to mimic the way multicast was done. The problem is that when I receive a packet I need a way to tell if it is multicast or unicast. I thought "multiRecv.receive(packet)" would only work on multicast packets, but apparently it can also work on unicast packets. Is there a way to tell either before or after doing .receive(packet) to detect which kind of packet it is?

I need to know because when I send out a response it has to be done using the same method as it was received. So if I receive unicast I need to send unicast and if I receive multicast I need to send multicast.

On another note, can a MulticastSocket also send a unicast message?

EDIT:
Although the accepted post is true, I was able to find a work around. By forcing the server sending the packet to me, to use different ports for unicast and multicast, I was able to figure out which one it was by using packet.getPort().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need a way to tell if it is multicast or unicast. I thought "multiRecv.receive(packet)" would only work on multicast packets, but apparently it can also work on unicast packets. Is there a way to tell either before or after doing .receive(packet) to detect which kind of packet it is?

Not in Java. In the BSD Sockets API there is a feature to retrieve the target address of a datagram, but it isn't implemented in Java.

> I need to know because when I send out a response it has to be done using the same method as it was received. So if I receive unicast I need to send unicast and if I receive multicast I need to send multicast.

Sorry, can't help you in Java.

> On another note, can a MulticastSocket also send a unicast message?

Yes. And further note that you don't need a `MulticastSocket` to *send* multicasts, and you don't need to join the group just to send either.

Comment: Do you think if I tried to receive a multicast packet on a DatagramSocket, I would get some sort of null value or error that could be used to tell it wasn't unicast and therefore must be multicast? I've tried doing this but so far it just seems to break out of the function I put that line in.

Comment: A `DatagramSocket` can't join the multicast group, so it can't receive multicast datagrams. It won't get 'some sort of a null value': it just won't get anything except unicast datagrams.